# In the new Tyranid Codex (6th Edition) is the Close Combat Weapons bonus included in Unit profiles?

Tags: warhammer-40k

There have been some changes to the way Close combat weapons work for Tyranids.  The rule used to be, that Scything talons were the only CC weapon that would give a +1 Attack bonus.  Now it applies to all Tyranid CC weapons, but only when 2 pairs are used (basically a shift of where +1 attack bonuses will be in the Tyranid army for the CC Monstrous Creatures, and medium sized models with 4 arms)

Previously, the attacks were already reflected in Tyranid profiles.  I am wondering, with a new rule change, if this is still true.

If it is NOT reflected, then that would mean the Death Leaper is actually 5 attacks, and the Carnifex is actually 4 attacks using their basic set of weapons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It used to be that this was reflected by the use of parentheses, e.g. 3(4)

[This forum post](http://www.librarium-online.com/forums/40k-rules-help/205638-special-characters-multiple-close-combat-weapons.html) talks about this(although not in relation to the models you mentioned). The consensus seems to be that if it is not explicitly stated that it is factored into the profile, then it's in addition to the profile.

Comment: This seemed to be the best answer.  GW could have make it a little more intuitive, but otherwise, I think this answer seems best.  Most of the basic CC weapon configurations in the new Codex would add an additional attack to the Tyranid profiles.

Answer (score 0):

Think it's clearly stated in the Tyranid codex:

> Designer's Note: Tyranid Melee weapons come as pairs. For game
>   purposes, each pair is treated as a single Melee weapon. This means
>   that Tyranid models must fight with two pairs of any Tyranid Melee
>   weapons to gain a bonus Attack in close combat for fighting with two
>   weapons. - Page 111 (Interactive codex)